# Installing zoom-client Snap

Tags: snap, video-streaming

I need to use Zoom video conferencing (https://zoom.us). While they offer a DEB package which works, this is exactly the type of application I'd prefer to run as a Snap. There is a Snap available (https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client), and even when you add all the additional connections it recommends, I cannot get it to work. After a reboot, running `snap run zoom-client` the application just returns to the prompt. The log file in `~/snap/zoom-client/current/.zoom/logs` contains the following lines:

```
ZoomLauncher started.
cmd line: 
CreateReportChannel bp_server_fd=4
$HOME = /home/user/snap/zoom-client/61 
Can't load/home/user/snap/zoom-client/61/.config/zoomus.conf
export SSB_HOME=/home/user/snap/zoom-client/61/.zoom; export QSG_INFO=1; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/snap/zoom-client/61/zoom; export BREAKPAD_CLIENT_FD=3; /snap/zoom-client/61/zoom/zoom "" 
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
zoom started.
[CZPClientLogMgr::LogClientEnvironment] [MacAddr: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][client: Linux][OS: Ubuntu Core 18][Hardware: CPU Core:2 Frenquency:2.5 G Memory size:15945MB CPU Brand:Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz GPU Brand:][Req ID: ]
Linux Client Version is 3.5.383291.0407
QSG_RENDER_LOOP is 
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = ubuntu:GNOME;   GDMSESSION = ubuntu
Graphics Card Info:: 
Zoom package arch is 64bit, runing OS arch is x86_64
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 8.33 ms
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 200)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
success to create child process,status is 35584.
zoom exited normally.
Something went wrong while running zoom,exit code is 139.
ZoomLauncher exit.
```

I am guessing the `Can't load/home/user/snap/zoom-client/61/.config/zoomus.conf` is just because the application has not run properly yet to create the config (I have also tried copying the config file created by the DEB version and this suppresses this message).

I have no idea what the `SSB_HOME` is about. I believe my PulseAudio setup is okay, as the speakers and microphone work with the DEB version aswell as with other applications.

I am running Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error relating to the Nvidia was fixed by @ogra's update, the second error related to a font issue. A purge of the font cache at both user and system level solve the issue.

```sh
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
```

Credits:

- https://github.com/ogra1/zoom-snap/issues/2
- https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapped-app-not-loading-fonts-on-fedora-and-arch/12484/24

Answer (score 1):

sorry, this is caused by the nvidia-4XX drivers, the issue is tracked at:

https://github.com/ogra1/zoom-snap/issues/2

EDIT: though your error looks slightly different, could you post the teminal log as described in the other issue to a pastebin (or open a new issue on github), so i can inspect it a bit deeper ?

Answer (score 1):

Try zoom thru flat, https://flathub.org/apps/details/us.zoom.Zoom, this one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This fix it for me:

- Uninstalling Zoom,
- Delete the zoom folder: rm -rf ~/.zoom
- Reinstall zoom

Now I'm able to launch and use the software

P.S. I'm using the deb package from zoom.com directly.